# Restoring Unity after installing Gnome3

Tags: 11.04, unity, gnome

For going back from gnome3 to stock 11.04 are these commands enough ? I am facing problems after running these commands .

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Can you add a description of what those "problems" are to the question?

Comment: I don't get any shell option to login except lxde which i had to install to boot into ubuntu.

Comment: Make sure ubuntu-desktop is installed

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not possible to revert back to gnome 2.x after installing gnome 3

Comment: I checked that myself week ago. That was not possiple. But maybe now it is? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure [ubuntu-desktop](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-desktop) [image: Install ubuntu-desktop]
is installed.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

solve the problem.