# Unity is disturbed after a partial upgrade

Tags: 11.04, unity, upgrade, dpkg, partial-upgrade

I had upgraded my workstation from Maverick to Natty. I switched to unity after this upgrade and was quite happy. In the last week of May, 2011 update manager proposed a partial upgrade.

After the partial-upgrade following changes has appeared.

- Login screen changed and looks like Gnome3 top panel (Clock in middle, Turn off option button on right, background is solid blue)
- GTK Controls are roughly rendered like Redmond theme.
- Appearance application is no where in the system to select between themes.
- No desktop, No panels, No lens just blackout except mouse arrow.
- Alt-Tab only works to switch between apps and Synapse to launch new apps.

NOTE: I added the gnome3 ppa but never tried to install it. Is this root of destruction?

How to restore it? It is urgent as it is my workstation. Thanks for any suggestion.

Here is dpkg.log http://pastebin.com/GRbwM86P that indicates the changes by partial upgrade.

---

I tried `unity --replace` that reloaded the unity and caused few changes

- Unity panels are appeared but theme is still disturbed
- Window decoration has lost close/min/max buttons and rendered in top panel only when maximized.
- No refreshed desktop rendering. An application minimized or moved left patterns on wallpaper area.
  *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the PPA is likeley the cause of your problems, try this:

- [Restoring Unity after installing Gnome3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39691/restoring-unity-after-installing-gnome3)

Answer (score 1):

If you add a PPA to your package sources the package manager looks there for updates, just like with any other package source. In your case it seems that the package manager, indeed, installed some updates from the Gnome3 PPA that are incompatible with Unity.

See [Restoring Unity after installing Gnome3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39691/restoring-unity-after-installing-gnome3) for how to get rid of them.